# How to continually get the current foreground window?

Tags: c#, events, window, foreground

I want to write a process that knows all the time what is the current foreground window.

I know i can use GetForegroundWindow in a loop but i believe it will be better not to check GetForegroundWindow all the time.

so what i'm looking for is something like an event OnForegroundWindowChanged or another method to do so.

I know i can writing an hook in C++ to every process and send the event from there but i prefer doing it all in c# and not to inject a dll to all running process (it don't sounds so stable :)

Thanks,

Omri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want is handling of UIAutomationEvents?

Admittedly this is part of windows accessibility functionality and I'm not sure if its always on or requires enabling, but [Try here for pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).